# Is there a way to purchase an Office License that'll work for X number of machines?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, license

A little question really regarding Office Licenses - is there a way to purchase an Office License giving you access to X number of machines on that license - so that when you install Office you aren't actually required to input any license details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This is called *Volume Licensing* by Microsoft. I believe the current incarnation uses a license server which sits on the local network and communicates with Microsoft to manage the active license keys. No license information is entered in the clients, which instead seek out the license server and request a license from it; Licensing for Windows 7 Enterprise functions in a similar manner.

Previously, Microsoft used "VLKs" or volume license keys, special keys which could be used with VLK versions of Microsoft software to activate as many times as needed with the threat of legal action keeping companies from overusing the key or distributing it. These keys could successfully be used to activate software on recovery images used by corporate IT at creation time without having to deal with the mess of re-activating each system each time they are re-imaged.

The term *Multi-Seat* licensing is also used to refer to this type of licensing, where a single license is designed to cover 10s, 100s, or even 1000s of installations on computers or "seats".

Comment: Do you have a link to a site explaining how Volume Licensing purchasing works?  IIRC, there are a bunch of possible gotchas, particularly for smaller organizations.

Comment: @ChimneyImp I'm afraid not. I've managed the software itself before (installing, licensing, maintenance), but not the actual purchase of licenses.

Comment: thanks anyway.  I looked this up on MS's site at one point and the software end seemed pretty comprehensible, but I could not make heads or tails of the business end.

Answer (score 3):

You can get an Office 2010 [Volume License](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/about-licensing/office2010.aspx).

Volume licences are licensed per device, but, to my understanding, they'll still require a key (they'll all use the same key).

Another option would be the [OEM Preinstallation Kit (OPK)](http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/installation/downloads/Pages/office_2010_opk.aspx#fbid=JersTylSeEi), but, to my understanding (and as the name implies), that's only available to OEMs.